# Sed delete line if nth character is not specific character

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a csv file, and I want to delete lines if their 12th character is not `;`.

So, for example, my file looks like this:

```
2266308;A;B;dfsgsfdg    
2266309;A;BJHSADFK;gfsdg
2266310;A;B;dfg
```

and I want:

```
2266308;A;B;dfsgsfdg
2266310;A;B;dfg
```

How can I remove a line if the 12th character in it is NOT `;` with sed? =)

Comment: You are asking two different questions here. Do you want to delete lines whose Nth *character* is not `;` or lines whose Nth *field* is >1 in length?

Comment: delete lines whose Nth character is not ; - this one)

Comment: Are you sure? If you're working with field-based data, it makes more sense to deal with fields instead of characters. What if one of the lines starts with a space? What if one fo the lines has a longer 1st field than you expect?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure, but thanks for option =) My file is well aligned and that would be the best case for solution in my opinion =)

Comment: But it is an option actually, depends on which way is easier to declare in sed =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete all lines whose 12th character is not `;`, you could do:

```
 $ sed -E '/^.{11}[^;]/d' file
2266308;A;B;dfsgsfdg    
2266310;A;B;dfg
```

Or, to edit the original file (if your `sed` supports `-i`):

```
$ sed -iE '/^.{11}[^;]/d' file
```

And if your `sed` doesn't support `-E`:

```
sed -i '/^.\{11\}[^;]/d' file
```

However, since this is a csv file, it is much safer to use fields instead of character counts. For example, use `awk` and tell it to print all lines whose 3rd field is one character long:

```
$ awk -F';' 'length($3)==1' file
2266308;A;B;dfsgsfdg    
2266310;A;B;dfg
```

With recent GNU awk, you can edit the file in place:

```
 awk -iinplace -F';' 'length($3)==1' file
```

This has the advantage of being robust to changes in the lengths of the preceding fields. Unlike the `sed` approach, it won't fail if you have leading whitespace on a line or if any of the 1st 2 fields are longer (or shorter) than you expect. As a general rule, if your data is field-separated, using the fields is a better idea than using character positions.

Comment: You have forgot the `-i` option, to edit the file in place: `sed -i -E '/^.{11}[^;]/d' file`

Comment: `sed -i` ain't portable to e.g. OpenBSD.

Comment: @thrig true but most implementations (including [FreeBSD](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/sed/), ) do. But OK, I added a disclaimer.

Comment: can't seem to restrain impulse to upvote every time I see `awk -iinplace`